# RabbitMQ management not visible after installation

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to install Rabbitmq on local machine..
I have initially downloaded Erlang v23.1 and then rabbitmq for windows.

The RabbitMQ service is running but i can't see the management interface.
I ran the command

***rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management***

I am getting below result
[image]

The tutorial which i follow say that it should be something like

[image].

I noted that i have missing some plugins. Can this be a reason why rabbitmq managment interface is not visible. If yes how can i install those..

Comment: Did you try opening the management console on the browser and what does it say...

Comment: yes i am trying on browser by typing the default address which is localhost:15672. No results